# Disable physical keyboard for certain edittext fields in android

Tags: android, input, external

I am attempting to build a kiosk app on an android tablet. I have a credit card reader that works like a physical keyboard. The card reader reads data from the magnetic strip of the credit card and displays them in a textfield.

Since the credit card reader acts as a physical keyboard, it shows the magnetic card content when the focus is on any textfield. Is there anyway I could disable the text from the card reader showing up on certain textfields?